# Windows Converting a Folder of Files From RTF to UTF-8

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to analyze a corpus of 620 Korean language newspaper articles using the konlpy module in Python. The files are in rtf formatting. However konlpy only supports files encoded in UTF-8. In Windows, how can I convert a folder containing 620 rtf encoded articles to UTF-8 articles such that, upon opening the files in Notepad, the Korean characters are still in-tact?

Some things I have tried (but to no avail)

Used a freeware converter program (http://www.emreakkas.com/localization-tools/convert-rtf-to-txt) that converted the files into UNICODE and then tried to use a Cygwin iconv batch file to convert the files using the same script as this individual did:

[cygwin syntax error near unexpected token `done'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389176/cygwin-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-done)

When I do this all of the files are there but they are 0KB and they are blank. (let me know if you need more info about this method as i needed to do another step to get this to even loop over my files)

Used another freeware program (memory a little hazy on this one) that converted the rtf files but all the characters were just scrambled latin characters.

I'm thinking that there has to be an easy way to do this, but everything I tried is really complicated and does not work. Another funny thing is that whenever I simply manually take the original rtf file or the file converted into UNICODE and "Save As" and choose UTF-8, it works fine. I would love it if I did not have to "Save As" for 620 articles.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: If you are more familiar with Python rather than Cygwin-Bash, why don't you write a short Python script that loops over the "Unicode" (probably UTF-16) files and saves them with UTF-8?

Comment: Btw, looking at the [KoNLPy docs](http://konlpy.org/en/v0.4.4/api/konlpy/), it seems that many methods for reading/loading data offer an `encoding` parameter – are you sure that the methods you need only support UTF-8, as you say? RTF input won't work (because it's not an encoding, but a format for markup – think HTML), but the "Unicode" versions can be loaded maybe. Try `encoding='UTF-16'` when loading such a file.

Comment: Two great suggestions! I will try both of those!